# Search for elements with same class names in webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I need to write script for drop-down boxes. There are two dropdown elements on same screen and both the dropdown boxes have got similar class names (Dropdown boxes are of search and select kind),and there is no unique-id for any element.
So the script works fine to select element from first dropdown, But it fails when it supposed to perform same for second dropdown.

Do reply

Regards

```
<div class="title-edit-form" id="49156080-2097-ea0f">
<div class="control-group required">
<label class="control-label">Title
</label>
<div class="controls row-fluid">
<div class="select2-container span12 select2-container-active select2-dropdown-open"   id="s2id_title">    
<a href="#" onclick="return false;" class="select2-choice" tabindex="-1">   
<span>de</span>
<abbr class="select2-search-choice-close" style="display:none;">
</abbr>   
<div>
<b></b>
</div>
</a>    
</div>
<input class="span12" id="title" type="hidden" style="display: none;" value="-1">
</div>
</div>
<div class="select2-drop select2-drop-active" style="display: block; top: 177px; left: 536px; width: 530px;">   
<div class="select2-search">       
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" class="select2-input select2-focused" tabindex="-1" style="">   
</div>   
<ul class="select2-results">
<li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable select2-new">
<div class="select2-result-label">
<span class="select2-match">de</span>
</div>
</li>
<li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable">
<div class="select2-result-label">
<span class="select2-match">De</span>
"an"
</div>
</li>
<li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable select2-highlighted">
<div class="select2-result-label">
"Stu"
<span class="select2-match">de</span>
"nt"
</div>`enter code here`
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: can you drop your html?

Answer (score 1):

the best way is to use `cssSelector()` for that kind of things, and especially the `nth-child()` function from `cssSelector()`.

Exemple :

```
// gets the first div that contains school as a class value.
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.school:nth-child(1)"));
```

[More about cssSelector()](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

[exemple wokring here -> JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gNGZq/)